# imagick readImageFile aborts script

Tags: php, imagick

I want to convert a picture with imagick in php.

Code:

```
$fp_pdf = fopen("tmp/test.png", 'rb');
$img = new imagick();
$img->readImageFile($fp_pdf);
```

My error.log:

```
[Tue Aug 18 15:29:42.364607 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1548:tid 524] AH00428: Parent: child process 3600 exited with status 3221226519 -- Restarting.
PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1681 but version 1680 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Aug 18 15:29:42.397611 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1548:tid 524] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 18 15:29:42.397611 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1548:tid 524] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 12:58:29
[Tue Aug 18 15:29:42.397611 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1548:tid 524] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Tue Aug 18 15:29:42.398611 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1548:tid 524] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1728
PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1681 but version 1680 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Aug 18 15:29:42.729644 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1728:tid 468] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

The script just aborts and I get no PHP error. [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

Comment: you have a library mismatch, and it's already warning you: "may behave surprisingly". fix the mismatch.

Comment: I am using Apache on Windows and this dll was the only one that I could install. Isnt there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You could install both Imagick and ImageMagick from the same place:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/imagick/

Which should allow the correct versions to be installed.

Comment: I already installed the current versions of imagick and imagemagick but it seems the current image magic version is too new (1682). Still a version conflict. Cant find an installer for image magick for the 1681.